# Ancora Interna sem criar histórico

Tags: javascript, html

estou enfrentando um problema relacionada com as ancoras internas do html, toda vez que uso uma é criado um histórico para cada ancora(Vejam na img abaixo). Há alguma maneira de impedir que crie esse histórico ?

[image: Histórico]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com *JavaScript*, você pode criar uma função para abrir seus links usando `location.replace()`.

> The `replace()` method replaces the current document with a new one.
>
> The difference between this method and `assign()`, is that `replace()` removes the URL of the current document from the document history, meaning that it is not possible to use the "back" button to navigate back to the original document.
>
> Fonte: [Location replace() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_loc_replace.asp)

Em livre tradução:

> O método `replace()` substitui o documento atual por um novo.
>
> A diferença entre este método e `assign()` é que `replace()` **remove a URL do documento atual do histórico do documento**, o que significa que não é possível usar o botão "voltar" para navegar de volta ao documento original.

Veja este exemplo:

```js
function abreLink(e, url) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.location.replace(url);
}
```

```html
<a href="http://google.com.br" onclick="abreLink(event, 'http://pt.stackoverflow.com');">Abrir link sem deixar histórico</a>
```

Comment: era exatamente isso que procurava. Agora aproveitando essa questão, há algum modo de chamar essa função, usando o header do php ?

Exemplo: Header("Location: index.php?email=".$email."abreLink");

Comment: O `header('Location: ...');` segue o mesmo princípio. Acontece que só fica registrado no histórico a página que o usuário cai no final.

Comment: Muito obrigado por tudo !